# Jquery Full calendar ignore timezone not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using Jquery full Calendar v2.5.0 and trying to Ignore the timezone but it doesn't work at all. When I change the timezone in the computer, Calendar changes all the values to new time zone.How can I correct this?

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            year: y,
            month: m,
            date: d,

            theme: true,
            columnFormat: {
                 week: 'ddd d',
                day: 'dddd'
            },

            timezone: false,
            header: {
                left: valLeft,
                center: 'title',
                right: valRight
            },
            titleFormat: {
                   day: 'MMM d, yyyy'
            },
            defaultView: ViewType,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: selectDate,
            height: 780,
            editable: true,
            events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
            eventDrop: eventDropped,
            eventResize: eventResized,
            allDaySlot: true,

            eventRender: function (event, element) {

            },
            eventClick: function (event, element) {

            }
        });
```

Json Result from JsonResponse.ashx

```
[
   {
      id:'1',
      Type:'262147',
      title:' Account : Alstonville Community Health, Contact : Jane Kulas, Regarding : brisbane, dragged 4pm, popup shows 5pm',
      start:1450764000,
      end:1450765800,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BLN'
   },
   {
      id:'2',
      Type:'262146',
      title:' Account : Aarat Dsitrict Hospiatl, Contact : lorriane Patterson, Regarding : T2',
      start:1450789200,
      end:1450792800,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BL0'
   },
   {
      id:'3',
      Type:'262145',
      title:' Account : ALBURY BASE HOSPITAL, Contact : Karen Hanel, Regarding : 8am-22_12_15 1 hour',
      start:1450731600,
      end:1450738800,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BL6'
   },
   {
      id:'4',
      Type:'262147',
      title:' Account : AASTN Victorian Branch, Contact : Celia Haberl, Regarding : adelaide, drag from 1pm, pop up shows 1:30 pm',
      start:1450751400,
      end:1450753200,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BLM'
   },
   {
      id:'5',
      Type:'262147',
      title:' Account : ALBURY COMMUNITY HEALTH CENTRE, Contact : Liz Fuchsen, Regarding : perth, dragged from 8am, pop up shows 11',
      start:1450731600,
      end:1450735200,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BLK'
   },
   {
      id:'6',
      Type:'262146',
      title:' Account : AASTN Victorian Branch, Contact : Celia Haberl, Regarding : NB',
      start:1450710000,
      end:1450713600,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BL4'
   },
   {
      id:'7',
      Type:'262147',
      title:' Account : AASTN Victorian Branch, Contact : Celia Haberl, Regarding : perth, dragged from 9am, popup shows 12',
      start:1450746000,
      end:1450747800,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BLL'
   },
   {
      id:'8',
      Type:'262145',
      title:' Account : Aarat Dsitrict Hospiatl, Contact : lorriane Patterson, Regarding : dragged from 3.30 - 4.00 AM Melbourne2',
      start:1450801800,
      end:1450803600,
      allDay:false,
      Completed:'No',
      description:'V6UJ9A000BMD'
   }
]
```

Comment: @GuruprasadRao isn't that for the older versions of FullCalendar?

Comment: Oh Sorry.. My bad.. Forgot to check the version you are using..